# Is there an object that compares smaller than any valid datetime.datetime(...)?

Tags: python, python-datetime

Is there a `MIN` constant for `datetime`?

I need it to represent the expiration date of a resource, and I want to have a `datetime` that represents "always expires" as default value (instead of `None` so I can use the same expiration comparison no matter what).

So right now I'm using `datetime.datetime(datetime.MINYEAR,1,1,0,0,tzusc())` as my  `MIN datetime` but I wonder if there is some other way to represents "the lowest possible time" (even if it's not a `datetime`).

Comment: What is the definition of *the beginning of time* ?

Comment: You could just use [`datetime.datetime.fromordinal(1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromordinal), or `fromtimestamp` if your other dates will be after the start of 1970.

Comment: What about [`datetime.datetime.min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min)

Comment: I guess something that compares lower to any other date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try - [`datetime.datetime.min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min) . According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min) -

> **`datetime.min`**
>
> The earliest representable datetime, datetime(MINYEAR, 1, 1, tzinfo=None).

Comment: How could I miss that from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `time.gmtime(0)` which is the epoch.

[Time Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

> The epoch is the point where the time starts. On January 1st of that year, at 0 hours, the “time since the epoch” is zero. For Unix, the epoch is 1970. To find out what the epoch is, look at gmtime(0).

Comment: There are dates prior to the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` it will gives you:

```
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

> Return the local date corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is
>   returned by time.time(). This may raise ValueError, if the timestamp
>   is out of the range of values supported by the platform C localtime()
>   function. It’s common for this to be restricted to years from 1970
>   through 2038. Note that on non-POSIX systems that include leap seconds
>   in their notion of a timestamp, leap seconds are ignored by
>   fromtimestamp().